# Does a copied syntactic object have to c-command what it was copied from?

Tags: syntax, minimalism

I think this is the case but I can't find any sources saying so. Mind helping me out?

I know Internal Merge necessarily guarantees that a copied syntactic object c-commands its lower copies, but the thing I have in mind is different. To be more precise:

1) It is hard for the children to poop.

According to Hornstein 1999, "the children" starts off in Spec,vP and moves up to embedded Spec,TP. How is the PP "for the children" made then? By copying "the children" and then External Merging it onto the P head "for," at which point the PP "for the children" Merges onto AP? Doesn't this violate the c-command condition for copies? I need some kind of text which says this is impossible.